# DNS SRV for TCP service and HTTP redirection

Tags: domain-name-system, srv-record

I have a subdomain, let's say it's called `service.example.com`. I want to set up this domain to redirect all HTTP(S) (`80` and `443`) calls to the apex domain `example.com` and the rest of requests to specific TCP port (`60000`) to my service. Can I do it with DNS SRV entry?

Comment: No. this has to be done via a basic web server configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do it with DNS SRV entry?

No, because technically yes (`SRV` records were designed for that), but in practice no, as browsers DO NOT use `SRV` records. So you can publish them in your DNS zone, but they won't be used.

The newest standard should come out "soon", it will create (they already exist on the field) new DNS records called `SVCB` and `HTTPS` for that exact need (including "CNAME at apex" feature, among other things), where browsers already agreed to implement it, and in fact did. That is the path you should be looking at, taking into account there will be a long tail of old clients (not up to date browsers) that won't know how to use those records, so you need to mitigate for that.

Comment: Wow! Learning something new every day! :)
Looks like I'll need to do it on a service level.
Great answer BTW, thank you